# Extract last instance of a regular expression from string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a URL that is in the following structure: http://somewebsite.com/directory1/directory2/directory3...

I'm trying to get the last directory name from this url, but the depth of the url isn't always  constant so i don't think i can use a simple substr or preg_match call - is there a function to get the last instance of a regular expression match from a string?

Comment: It looks like [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) would be sufficient here? If not, what is the regex in question?

Comment: preg_match('/\/([^/])$/' ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
basename( $url )
```

It should have the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

**Torben's answer is the correct way to handle this specific case.** But for posterity, here is how you get the last instance of a regular expression match:

```
preg_match_all('/pattern/', 'subject', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$last_match = end($matches); // or array_pop(), but it modifies the array
```

`$last_match[0]` contains the complete match, `$last_match[1]` contains the first parenthesized subpattern, etc.

Another point of interest: your regular expression `'/\/([^/])$/'` should work as-is because the `$` anchors it to the end.